# Reaching server when request is redirected to form

Tags: android, forms, redirect, authentication, wifi

I have an issue with wifi connectivity when a browser form must be completed before internet access is granted. The user (if using a browser) is redirected to a login form requiring them to login or sign up for wifi access. 
The users are not using a browser but a request from my app to the server is redirected to a login form making the server unreachable. Is there a graceful way of detecting this behaviour and at least warning the user of the issue.. 
In many cases the mobile network is available and switching off wifi is all that is required.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP redirect has a specific response code (well, several specific response codes, from 300 to 307). You could read the responseCode before assuming that you have a connection and handle the failure from that point.

A redirect should also have a Location value in the response header, so you could conceiveably capture that value and launch a WebView, passing Location as the URL, giving the user access to the login form. This would get a little complex, though, depending on how the session is validated - if there's a cookie, for instance, you'd have to extract it from the form response and store it for future requests from your native code. Often these sessions employ the MAC address, in which case you wouldn't have to do anything else (apart from handle a successful login and try your request again).

I hope that's helpful.